# 'Uncaught TypeError: vairable.fadeOut is not a function' in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout

I'm trying to set a classname to a variable and then fadeOut(). I'm able to use fadeOut() on the query selector directly, but not when I store it in a variable.

Here's my code:

```
var sections = ["$('.start')", "$('.one')", "$('.two')", "$('.three')", "$('.four')", "$('.five')", "$('.six')","$('.seven')","$('.eight')"];
var begin = $('.begin');

var i = 0;
var currentSection = sections[i];
var nextSection;

begin.on('click', function(){
  for(i=0; i < sections.length; i++){
    console.log(currentSection);
    currentSection.fadeOut();
    currentSection = sections[i+1];
  }
});
```

Here's a video with no sound showing what's up: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbj3rvl8YF

Am I missing something?

Here's the link to my CodePen for the rest of the code: https://codepen.io/naturalhanglider/collab/bd90327af7cb6da2620e3a3c4d7f398f/?editors=1010

I dug around, and wasn't able to find what I was looking for. Please point me in the right direction if this question has been asked before!

Comment: Elements inside `sections` are not objects but strings, they don't have `fadeOut` functions.

Comment: Replace, for instance, `"$('.start')"` with `$('.start')`.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this. first add unique id to your html like this

```
<section class="start">
  <p><div class="begin button">Begin</div></p>
</section>
<section id="section-1" class="one hidden">
<div class="bg">
 <p class="overlay">Section One</p>
</div>
</section>
<section id="section-2" class="two hidden">
 <p>Section Two</p>
</section>
<section id="section-2" class="three hidden">
 <p>Section Three</p>
</section>
<section id="section-4" class="four hidden">
 <p>Section Four</p>
</section>
<section id="section-5" class="five hidden">
  <p>Section Five</p>
</section>
<section id="section-6" class="six hidden">
  <p>Section Six</p>
</section>
<section id="section-7" class="seven hidden">
 <p>Section Seven</p>
</section>
<section id="section-8" class="eight hidden">
 <p>Section Eight</p>
</section>
```

and your javascript code in foor loop retrieve them like this

```
var sections = [$('.start'), $('.one'), $('.two'), $('.three'), $('.four'), $('.five'), $('.six'),$('.seven'),$('.eight')];
var begin = $('.begin');

var i = 0;

begin.on('click', function(){
  for(i=0; i < sections.length; i++){
    console.log(currentSection);
    var currentSection = $("#section-"+i);
    currentSection.fadeOut();
  }
});
```

i dont know what you are tryinng to fade cause i cant see any html in codepen but your error will not occur again by doing this.

OR you can also do like this

```
begin.on('click', function(){
   sections.forEach(function(element) {
     console.log(element);
     element.fadeOut();
     console.log(element);
```

});

Comment: What's the point of the new `id` attributes when the elements already have unique classes? In your suggested code you never access the elements of `sections`, you only access the array's length, which makes the array a bit pointless.

Comment: wel if you hava unique class with different name then you cant retrieve ii inside loop. you can use class also but with unique number for example class-1, class-2, class-3

Comment: Your loop could just iterate over the array call `.fadeOut()` on each element, much like the OP tried to do in their code. My original point was that you kept the array, and fixed it so it contained actual jQuery objects rather than strings, but then didn't use any of those objects.

Comment: well she has hard coded the object which means the length of object will be static and there is no much difference. and what dose OP means i really want to know